# How to call function after you get data back from .subscribe() in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't seem to find an answer that works. I have an observable that I'm subscribing to like so:

```
this.contentfulService.weekNumber
    .subscribe(
        (weekNumber) => { this.weekNumber = weekNumber; }
    );
```

and I want to do something after the data has been received and put into my variable `this.weekNumber` I have tried doing this:

```
this.contentfulService.weekNumber
    .subscribe(
        (weekNumber) => { weekNumber = this.weekNumber; },
        (error) => { console.log(error); },
        () => { console.log(this.weekNumber); }
    );
```

but I'm not getting the `console.log`? Im only using the console.log as a test, I actually want to use the data that is in `this.weekNumber` to populate something but when I put it right after the `weekNumber = this.weekNumber` I get undefined so I need to be able to call a function after `this.weekNumber` has been defined

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `this.weekNumber = weekNumber` instead of `weekNumber = this.weekNumber;`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed still not getting the console.log

Comment: `.subscribe(
        (weekNumber) => { this.weekNumber =weekNumber; console.log(this.weekNumber); });`

Comment: Is `(weekNumber) => { weekNumber = this.weekNumber; },` is working? Please have a log there and check if that's working.

Comment: @AnkitaGupta we can have a third callback that runs as a `finally` callback. OP wants to use that maybe.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed @AnkitaGupta Sorry my question is more like, once I assign `this.weekNumber = weekNumber` I want the data in `this.weekNumber` to be used on the page so when I put that directly under `this.weekNumber = weekNumber` I get undefined so I need to have a function that runs after `this.weeknumber` has been populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not assigning values in the correct way. Please check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_assignment_operators_examples.htm) tutorial.

Change your code as shown below:

```
    this.contentfulService.weekNumber
        .subscribe(
            (weekNumber) => { 
                    this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
                    console.log(this.weekNumber);
 },
            (error) => { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: Sorry my question is more like, once I assign `this.weekNumber = weekNumber` I want the data in `this.weekNumber` to be used on the page so when I put that directly under `this.weekNumber = weekNumber` I get undefined so I need to have a function that runs after `this.weeknumber` has been populated

Comment: Still not get you. Can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

I think your subscription must be something like this:

```
this.contentfulService.weekNumber
    .subscribe(
        weekNumber => { 
                this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
                console.log(this.weekNumber); }, error => { console.log(error); });
```

Now you wont get this.weekNumber is undefined because you will have the scope of this inside the function