# Run a function after subscription is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, es6-promise

I have some data stored in a Firebase Realtime Database.
I want my Angular application to load and show it when it starts. I have a TripService that loads data and a main AppComponent. In a TripService, I retrive the data using subscribe() method. However, I am having trouble sending this data to AppComponent. I tried converting this subscription to a Promise, but my solution doesn't work. Could you tell me what mistake am I making? Also, how do I make sure that AppComponent reads data after TripService loads it?

This is the most important code in trip.service.ts

```
export class TripService {
  trips: any;
  private db: AngularFireDatabase
  constructor(database: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.db = database;
  }

  async loadAllTrips(){
    this.db.list('trips').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({key: c.key, ...<Object>c.payload.val()}))))
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.trips = data;})
  }
}
```

This is the most important code in app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tripService.loadAllTrips()
      .then(() => {this.trips = this.tripService.trips;);
  }
  trips: any;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call function after you get data back from .subscribe() in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800733/how-to-call-function-after-you-get-data-back-from-subscribe-in-angular-5)

Comment: No no, I need the data in another component

Comment: This has nothing to do with components. It's how rxjs works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to use `Observale`

```typescript
export class TripService {
  trips: any;
  private db: AngularFireDatabase
  constructor(database: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.db = database;
  }

  loadAllTrips(){
    return this.db.list('trips').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({key: c.key, ...<Object>c.payload.val()}))))
  }
}
```

and in you app component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tripService.loadAllTrips()
      .subscribe(trips => this.trips = trips);
  }
  trips: any;
}
```

You simply return an observable and subscribe to it in your component

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you tried to convert it to promise, you did it wrong. you should have added `take(1)` to only take 1 event and then promise would be completed

```
async loadAllTrips(){
    return this.db.list('trips').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(changes =>
      changes.map(c =>
        ({key: c.key, ...<Object>c.payload.val()}))),
        take(1)
     ).toPromise(data => this.trips = data);
  }
```